# Not able to get the right size in auto-layout using systemLayoutSizeFittingSize

Tags: ios7, autolayout

I have a button which is designed in a UIView with 600, 600 size (any, any). The button is located at (40,40) and is of size (520, 80). The button is displayed in iPhone 4.0 retina display (320 x 568).

In viewWillAppear, I am getting the width of the button using the following code:
NSLog(@"%f", self.fullgameButton.frame.size.width); // returns 520.

In viewWillAppear, I am getting the size using systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:
CGSize size = [self.fullgameButton systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize]; // returns 403.

In viewDidAppear, I am getting the size of the button:
NSLog(@"%f", self.fullgameButton.frame.size.width); // returns 240.

When I get the size using systemLayoutSizeFittingSize, I am expect the button to return a width of 240. But, it is giving me an unusual value of 403. Any reason why I am getting such a value?